# Replace case insenstive in string

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a file and i converted that file into string. Now whenever i am trying to replace some camelcase data like 'fooBar' with lowercase data like 'foobar' then it is not working.

I tried these 2 cases.

```
   String target = "fooBar and tooohh";
  target = target.replace("foobar", "");
   System.out.println(target);
```

Its giving me this output `fooBar and tooohh`

Then I tried this

```
String target123 = "fooBar and tooohh";
target123=target123.replace("(?i)foobar", "") ;
System.out.println(target123);
```

and this also giving me same output : - `fooBar and tooohh`

Comment: Are you trying to lowercase the entire string or just the camelcased words?  And you do know you seem to be _trying_ to replace the word "foobar" with nothing (though as some answers below will tell you that can't work in Java)?

Comment: Instead of `replaceFirst` and `replaceAll` the method `replace` is a non-regex literal replace. You would have needed to do `replace("fooBar", "")` or use a regex method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [String::replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [String::replaceFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method and regex `(?i)foobar`

```
 String replaced = target.replaceAll("(?i)foobar", "");
```

or

```
String replaced = target.replaceFirst("(?i)foobar", "");
```

Method `String::replace` cann't be used with `regex`

Comment: But i don't want to replace all the string having same pattern in my string.

Comment: @Java_Alert then `replaceFirst`

Comment: @Java_Alert you cann't use `replace` with regex

Answer (score 1):

Just use [String.toLowerCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) method

So if you want to make whole string lower case you can do like

```
String result = test.toLowerCase();
```

Now if you only want to make the fooBar to lower case you can do somethinglike

```
String temp = "fooBar";
String result = test.replace(temp,temp.toLowerCase());
```

[Just tried to give a concept]

Answer (score 1):

As told by other String is immutable so you need to reassigne.

```
target = target.replace("foobar", "");
```

With [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) you can use a regex so for your needs:

```
target = target.replaceAll("(?i)foobar", "");
```

If you want to set all the string to lowercase then use [String.toLowerCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29)

```
target = target.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the string "foobar" which is not in "fooBar and tooohh". replace is case sensitive, so if you would want to replace "fooBar" with "" (nothing), you'd use:

```
string target = "fooBar and tooohh";
target = target.replace("fooBar", "");
```

This would return:

```
" and tooohh"
```

However, you've asked to lowercase all the camelcased words in which case you would do this:

```
string target = "fooBar and tooohh";
target = target.toLowerCase();
```

returns:

```
"foobar and tooohh"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `String` is **immutable** in java, so if you want to change a `String` with `replace()` method you have to reassigne your variable like this:

```
target = target.replace("foobar", "");
```

Comment: Hey i did that only, have updated the same.Actually i am looking for result and tooohh.

Comment: @Java_Alert if I get your requirement well, you want to create an lowercase text from a mixed (lower/upper case) text. In this case you can use [String.lowerCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) with reassign as well.

Answer (score 0):

[String#toLowerCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) is your answer to the problem.